# Is it possible to change partyID in opentaps/OFBiz?

Tags: ofbiz, opentaps

I am trying to create a meaningful group (party group) in opentaps 1.5.0 and I noticed that on the system there are groups with meaningful party IDs. However I can't find where on the system I can create meaningful party ids. For now the system just assigns auto generated numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options for this.

1) you can create the parties as part of your seed data. this is how those parties are created

2) you should expose the party id field in the party application of ofbiz and in the crm of opentaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create meaningful Ids from Back-end. Also at some place in back-end it is auto-generated, then you can Import XML and place the ID you want in xml fields and them import it into OFBiz.